# How many times does my code get data from iterator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, iterator, dataset

I use TFRecord to manage my dataset.

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(files)
dataset = dataset.map(...)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(...)
dataset = dataset.batch(...)
dataset = dataset.repeat(...)
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
image_batch, label_batch = iterator.get_next()
```

the output of net:

```
logits_batch = network(image_batch)
```

I use **tf.metrics** to show me the performance.

```
acc_value_op, acc_update_op = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=label_batch, predictions=predict_batch, name="accuracy")
```

and within the tf.Session() I have the following codes:

```
_, loss_value, g_step, _, summary = sess.run(
    [train_op, loss_op, g_step_op, acc_update_op, summary_op],
    feed_dict={handle: train_iterator_handle})
acc_value = sess.run(
    [acc_value_op],
    feed_dict={handle: train_iterator_handle})
```

I put acc_update_op before acc_value_op because I want to **update the metrics.accuracy first** then **get the result of metrics.accuracy**.

But what makes me confused is that

1) whether these two sess.run(...) will actually **get two batches of data** or **just the same one batch?**

2) and can I **get the newest acc value of one batch** just use

```
acc_value, _ = sess.run([acc_value_op, acc_update_op], feed_dict={.....})
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dataset iterators maintain a state between runs, so each time you call `run` your iterator will return a new different batch. If you want it to return the first batch again you would have to initialize the iterator.

The line:

```
acc_value, _ = sess.run([acc_value_op, acc_update_op], feed_dict={.....})
```

Will give you the most updated accumulated accuracy value, and it is actually equivalent to:

```
acc_value = sess.run(acc_update_op, feed_dict={.....})
```

Since the returned value of `acc_update_op` is the same as that of `acc_value_op` (see [`tf.metrics.accuracy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/accuracy)). The only difference between the two is that running the second will update the internal metric variables so that the next time you evaluate it it will reflect the accumulated value. Note that you can reset to zero the accumulated metrics running an op like this:

```
reset_metrics_op = tf.variables_initializer(tf.get_collection(METRIC_VARIABLES))
```

If you want to have both the batch and accumulated accuracy values, you can have a second metric for that:

```
batch_acc_value_op, _ = tf.metrics.accuracy(
    labels=label_batch, predictions=predict_batch, name="batch_accuracy")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply